# Replace string with this command

Tags: bash, sed, grep

```
find /home -iname ".htaccess" -exec grep -l "FollowSymLinks" {} \;
```

Do I add SED into the -exec so that I can do a find and replace of:

```
 +FollowSymLinks to +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

Comment: what did you already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
find /home -iname ".htaccess" -exec sed -i "s/FollowSymLinks/SymLinksIfOwnerMatch/g" {} \;
```